# return new AndroidMusic()

Tags: java, android

I'm studying the Beginning Android Games book and I'm really stuck and can't progress because of one tiny error being flagged up by Eclipse. Please can somebody tell me if there is anything wrong with this code snippet:-

```
  public Music newMusic(String filename) {
  try {
  AssetFileDescriptor assetDescriptor = assets.openFd(filename);
  return new AndroidMusic(assetDescriptor);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music '" + filename + "'");
  }
  }
```

The 'AndroidMusic' is being underlined and Eclipse says it cannot be resolved to a type and suggests I create a class for it...I just don't know what to do, the author of the book hasn't told me to create a class for it.

I really hope somebody can see where I've gone wrong...I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: Sounds like it may be something in the environment not set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple search for `"beginning android games" androidmusic` indicates:

- The book does describe an `AndroidMusic` class
- The source code for the book has an `AndroidMusic` class

In fact, based on that search, it would appear that if you read ahead a few pages from where you were told to enter in the code from your question, the author will show you how to implement that `AndroidMusic` class.